# Why can't I call a server function from the sidebar in Google AppScript for Sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

I'm having problems calling a server-side Apps Script function from a html sidebar in Google Sheets.

I've replicated my issue with the simple example code below.

#### What it should do

Clicking the button should call `alert` in my Code.gs script and display an alert to the user.

#### What actually happens

Clicking the button shows the error:

```
We're sorry, a server error occurred while reading from storage. Error code PERMISSION_DENIED.
```

There are no entries in the 'executions' section of the Apps Script dashboard for `alert()`, so it seems like the function never even gets called?

#### Code.gs:

```js
function onOpen() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Matthew')
    .addItem('Show Sidebar', 'sidebar')
    .addToUi();
};

function sidebar() {
  const html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('test.html')
    .setTitle('Matthew Experiment')
    .setWidth(300);

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);


}

function alert() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("alert!"); 
}
```

#### test.html (well the body)

```html
  <body>
    <div class="container">
       <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="doSomething()">Click Me!</button>
    </div>
    <script>
            function doSomething() {
          google.script.run.withFailureHandler(function(error) {
            console.log("error")
            console.log(error.message)
          }).withSuccessHandler(function(result) {
            console.log("done!")
          }).alert();
        }
    </script>
  </body>
```

I've confirmed that the client-code is getting properly inflated with server-side function names, it's just calling the function that doesn't work.

[image]

My code seems to be the same as all of the getting started guides, but I don't see anyone else posting about this issue. Hoping someone here has deeper knowledge of the problem than I do.

#### Update, even weirder

I opened a private window and it **worked**, so I thought, maybe this is an extension causing problems? But even disabling all extensions doesn't fix it in the main window. I've logged out/in to my google account but still can't get it to work without opening a private browser window.

This problem is consistent across chrome/edge/firefox.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60412319

Comment: According to the issuetracker, this only happens in chrome, when the global logged in user is different from the owner of script and spreadsheet.

Comment: I am both the owner of the script, and the owner of the spreadsheet, and it happens in FF too. :-(

Comment: ohoh, yes my primary user is my gmail account, and this is on my secondary account

Comment: @TheMaster I'll dig into that issue, you may have figured it out

Comment: From the code editor, manually run the `alert()` function -- does it work? Then try the sidebar again.

Comment: @MatthewRathbone was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60412319) eventually what caused this issue? Try using your primary email account to see if that actually works.

Comment: I have a strong suspicion this is a cookie permission issue. Especially cause browsers have been tightening security around cookies. I've also had issues with GAS projects when I'm logged into multiple Google accounts. I don't know how to test this theory though...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This happens when the global logged in user is different from the owner of script.

Logout all your google account and then re-login with the account you used to created the script. This fixed the issue.

Comment: this is such a terrible bug and means the sidebar is almost useless unless you're building a fully fledged add-in

Answer (score 1):

**Here's a simple example of a side bar dialog communicating with server**

```
function showMySideBar() {
  var html='<input type="button" value="Click Me" onClick="doSomething()" />';
  html+='<script>function doSomething(){google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(msg){window.alert(msg);}).pleaseHelp();}</script>';
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html));
 }

function pleaseHelp() {
  return 'What can I do to help?';
}
```