# google.script.run.function not working with Chrome V8

Tags: google-apps-script, v8

Here is my code for show a sidebar. When click at `OK` button, I will insert a new record to my sheet.
It **works well** when I disable V8 by `Run->Disable new App Script .. V8`.
When I enable V8, `onClicked` in `Code.gs` not fired anymore.
I have checked the [V8 Runtime Overview](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime#v8_syntax_examples) but I didn't find anything.

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="okClicked()"> OK </button>
    <button onclick="close()">Close </button>
    <script>
      function okClicked(){
          window.alert("A");
          google.script.run.okClicked();
      }
      
      function close(){
          google.script.host.close();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Code.gs**

```
function showSidebar() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index')
      .setTitle('My custom sidebar')
      .setWidth(300);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
}

function okClicked(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Data");
  sheet.appendRow(["A", "B"]);
}
```

Any help or suggestion would be great appreciated.

Comment: Read [mcve]- specifically describe the problem/error and not your inference of the error/problem. Like: *"when I click the button , nothing  happens. I added `console.log("Triggered")` inside `code.gs`, but nothing is logged on the "server console". On the client side, The following error is shown on the "browser console", when I click the button: .... "*

Comment: Unfortunaty, the code works for me great! Please, check that the book contains the 'Data' sheet.

Comment: What does the execution log show? Does it show a call to `okClicked`? If so, any error?

Comment: Also, how is `showSidebar` being called?

Comment: @contributorpw yes, I have 'Data' sheet, when I disable v8, everything working well

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan I run `showSidebar` by select this function -> then I click `Run` button. there is no error log display

Answer (score 3):

Someone posted an issue similar to `createHtmlOutputFromFile` and V8 on Google's [Issue  Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/149980602). You can check if this issue is adequate for your case and hit the Star to let them know you have the same issue.

If you believe that this issue does not correspond with yours, you can also create a new issue with your case there.

Comment: This might be more related to the issue you already linked  here https://stackoverflow.com/q/60412319 https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150247026

Comment: Thank you. I will follow the issue tracker

Answer (score 0):

### 2021 Answer

FWIW, I found that Google Apps Script was erroring out like this when my partner and I were both logged into the same Google account.

We also found that this can happen when new features have been built into your Google Apps Script / Sheets backend code that require updated permissions that haven't been granted yet. It's a bit hacky, but I fixed this by:

1. Sharing the sheet with another account I own
2. Logging into that account, then trying to run the function
3. Agreeing to grant the permissions asked by Google Auth / Scopes in the dialog that follows